# Make a visible primary link not clickable

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system, hyperlink

On my Drupal site I've got a set of Primary Links. The ones that expand I'd like to make the parent not click able e.g

```
  -home
  -about
    -history
    -website
```

Only home, history, website should link to a page. If the user clicks on `about`nothing should happen. I've tried searching around the admin panels as well as leaving the field blank but it doesn't seem to be working. I'd assume I'd have to hardcode this? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this module http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items

Its probably the simplest way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with it, the easiest solution is to use js to disable clicks.

Comment: How would I do that for a single item on a Primary Links menu?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `yourtheme_menu_item` function in template.php seems to be the way to go for this. The documentation for the original function is at http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_item

The function passes a `$has_children` variable and a `$menu` variable, so it should be pretty easy to adjust Primary Menu items with children as needed.

Some untested example code:

```
function yourtheme_menu_item($link, $has_children, $menu = '', $in_active_trail = FALSE, $extra_class = NULL) {
  // ... original theme code copy-pasted ...
  if ($has_children) {
    $modified_link_name = youtheme_write_menu_item_without_links($link);
    return '<li class="'. $class .'">'. $modified_link_name ."</li>\n";
  } else {
    // From original function
    return '<li class="'. $class .'">'. $link . $menu ."</li>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This will alter ALL menus on the site. Will almost certainly give problems.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add in the path the phrase `<nolink>`.

Answer (score 0):

"You just need to add in the path the phrase `<nolink>`"
i used this before and it worked, but for some reason it didn´t work for a different site that i am using now.
So i tried to write # in the path and worked fine for me.

Hug everybody.